# running more than 1000 workflow instances in SharePoint 2013 Workflows

Tags: workflow

My client will have more than 1000 active workflow instances running in SharePoint Server 2013.
I would like to know if SharePoint 2013 workflow can support this? 
How many workflow instances can be run in sharepoint?
What is the impact of all these workflows instances running at the same time?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Workflow here are the limitations for using Workflows in SharePoint 2013 according to Microsoft.

As you can see for example:

> Published workflow definitions per web site:
>
> 1,000 per web site
> Supported
>
> The maximum supported number of published workflow
> definitions per web site is 1,000.
>
> Total workflow associations per site:
>
> 1,799 per site
>
> Boundary:
>
> The Service Bus supports a maximum of 1,799 subscriptions per scope. This maximum value includes the sum of both published and unpublished associations.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your quick reply. I was looking at this article before and I saw that it states this: 15 is the maximum number of workflows allowed to be executing against a content database at the same time, excluding instances that are running in the timer service.

What is confusing me is this: 
published workflow definitions per web site is 1,000 and 15 workflows can be run agains a content database

Comment: Published workflows, and running and querying the content DB at the same time is two different things I guess :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SharePoint can handle more than 1000 running workflow instances. Once the workflow engine spots an asynchronous activity to be executed next, the state of the workflow instance will be stored in the Database. It's called 'Workflow State Dehydration'. And based on external triggers/events(form button click, timer etc.), the state will be loaded back into the 
process, then it'll continue executing further steps. So, 1000 is a perfectly valid number.